# dB context<> after the setting thin I can not retrieve the table bay the object of the dB Context

Tags: database, private, readonly

AFTER the dB set a table then I can not retrieve the table by the object of the DB context

how can get the table AFETR THE Db set a table through the object of the Db CONTEXT .
first I create the object of the Db context then try to get on table which I set through the Db set in  Db context class .then i CAN NOT get this table by the object of the Db context